# Firebase Authentication. General Query

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am currently creating a react-native app and testing it using exp on a physical Pixel 2. When I load my app up, I have the following in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount = () => {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{ 
        if (user) {
            //this.setState({userid: user.uid}); //I added this to see if it was the below slowing things down (it is not)
            firebase.database().ref('/Users/'+user.uid+'/Public/').once('value')
            .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
            .then(snapshot=>{

                let username = snapshot.child('Username').val();
                    this.setState({username: username, userid: user.uid});
                });

        } else {

            this.setState({ user: null, username: null});
        }

    });}
```

My aim is to direct the user to the log-in page if they are not authenticated. Otherwise, dive straight into the inner pages. My code sort-of-works and this does actually take place (hurray!).

However, when I load my app up is takes a number of seconds (maybe 10 seconds), for the app to realise that I am already signed in. This means it shows the log-in page for 10 seconds and then starts to display the inner pages. Has anyone got any idea of why it takes so long for `.onAuthStateChanged` to register that I am in fact still signed in from my last session? And is there any way for me to know whether I am at the login page because I am not logged in at all or because the app doesn't yet realise that I am logged in? It is very awkward for the user having to sign in every time and then mid way through typing their details in, being logged in lol!

As always, all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I don't think there is much you can do about how long it take firebase to check whether you are authenticated or not.  However, I would suggest showing a loading screen or spinner until you know whether to direct the user to the login or landing page.

Comment: But how will I know whether I am going to be directing the user to the login or landing page?

Comment: The issue is I don't know whether it is going to authenticate, hence I can't implement the loading screen.